# How to limit rows in query SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, row, limit

I am new SQL user. I am trying to limit the number of rows pulled on SQL Server Management Studio using the following query.

```
SELECT [Column A] 
FROM [DB].[Ordering In DB].[Table] 
WHERE [Column B] = 30 
LIMIT 3;
```

I get the following result.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Can `LIMIT` not be used in SQL Server Management Studio? In the end I only want to get to 3 or x number of rows. How do I do this?

Comment: Some dbms' such as Sql Server and Oracle do not support `limit`. Have you tried `select top 3 column_a from...`

Comment: For SQL Server, use `SELECT TOP (3) .......` - `LIMIT` is a MySQL/PostgreSQL custom feature - not available in T-SQL / SQL Server

Comment: @Isolated, SQL Server supports both TOP and the ISO-standard FETCH, where it's part of the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Isolated, with OFFSET..FETCH: `ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I know that. But I think you're original comment read "LIMIT" not "FETCH" and then you changed it. Once I saw it change (or my vision corrected) then I removed my comment.

Comment: @Isolated, sorry, the reference to limit was a typo and I had changed it before your comment to me.

Comment: Since you are asking specifically about `SQL Server Management Studio`: Settings > Query execution > Sql Server > Set rowcount: <value>

Answer (score 0):

You can use top 1,2,x

like

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Column A] 
FROM [DB].[Ordering In DB].[Table] 
WHERE [Column B] = 30 ;
```

Will be showed just 10 first rowns.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two things to limit your rows in SELECT query:

1. Use `TOP(Number_of_Rows_To_Be_Fetched)`:

   SELECT TOP(5) [Column A] FROM [Table] WHERE [Column B] = 30

This will fetch only 5 records.

2. Use `OFFSET` & `FETCH`

Here, OFFSET means the number of rows you want to skip from top.
FETCH means the next number of rows you want to fetch.

```
SELECT [Column A]
FROM [Table] 
WHERE [Column B] = 30
ORDER BY [Column A]
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

This query will skip first 2 rows and fetch next 3 rows.